# How can I read a simple txt file in Matlab in the fortran way (i.e. I want to keep reading after the newline)

Tags: matlab, fortran

I have to read the simple text file I write on the end of this post (it is just a sctructured grid). In fortran it is so easy to do this, you just have to do:

```
    read(fileunit,*)
    read(fileunit,*) mc,nc
    do j = 1, nc 
       read (fileunit, *) dummy, dummy, (xcor(j,i), i=1,mc) 
    enddo
```

is there an equivalent function in matlab that reads element by element and keeps reading after the newline like in fortran? I could not find it, all the function as fscanf, textscan etc read line by line and then i have to parse each line. Here is the file. thanks for any help A.

```
Gridfile version 8.675.44
8     3
eta=    1   0.00000000000000000E+00    1.50000000000000000E+02             
            4.50000000000000000E+02    6.00000000000000000E+02
            4.50000000000000000E+02    6.00000000000000000E+02
            4.50000000000000000E+02    6.00000000000000000E+02 
eta=    2   0.00000000000000000E+00    1.50000000000000000E+02      
            3.00000000000000000E+02    4.50000000000000000E+02    
            7.50000000000000000E+02    9.00000000000000000E+02 
            4.50000000000000000E+02    6.00000000000000000E+02 
eta=    3   0.00000000000000000E+00    1.50000000000000000E+02      
            3.00000000000000000E+02    4.50000000000000000E+02    
            7.50000000000000000E+02    9.00000000000000000E+02   
            4.50000000000000000E+02    6.00000000000000000E+02
```

Comment: Your goal is not clear to anyone who can't read fortran, myself included.

Comment: He wants to read the file using a statement or procedure that keeps reading on subsequent lines, when there was not enough content on the present one.

Comment: I added "and keeps reading after the newline like in fortran" to make it clearer, but it was already in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but perhaps you will like the way `fscanf` works, as in this example. After the file is opened by something like `fin = fopen('gridfile.txt')` and the header swallowed, you can use `fscanf(f, 'x= %d')`, and then `fscanf(f, '%f')`, which will read the entire block. `fscanf` **does not stop** at the end of a line if not instructed to do so. Taken together, a solution could look like

```
fin = fopen('gridfile.txt');
fgetl(fin);
% read data counts
cnt = fscanf(fin, '%d %d', 2);
mc = cnt(1);
nc = cnt(2);
xcor = zeros(nc, mc);
% read blocks of data
for j = 1 : nc
    fscanf(fin, '%s %s', 2);
    xcor(j, :) = fscanf(fin, '%f', mc)';
end
fclose(fin);
```

`fscanf` keeps matching the format specifier as long as possible, and returns only when no further consecutive matches can be found. The above examples uses this in two places. First, to extract the dimensionality `cnt`, in your example (8, 3), and second, to read eight consecutive floating point values per record.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working. Even replacing the typo "f" with "fin", it gives the error "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch" on the line before the end statement.

Comment: There were two typos of this kind. Just fixed those. I know it works, so let me know if you're still having trouble with this. I can have a closer look some time later today.

Comment: It does not work in general. I just posted an example using x= but actually most of my grid files are in curvilinear coordinates and they display eta= instead of x=. I edited the file above. In this case it does not work, the line "fscanf(fin, 'x= %d');" does not do the proper job and the pointer does not move (checked with  position = ftell(fin)) I do not know why.

Comment: A generalized dummy to swallow both `x= %d` and `eta= %d` would be `fscanf(fin, '%s %d')`.

Comment: thanks...but this still does not look like the fortran way because it is not general. what if instead of "eta=  1" i have "4.52E+02 2.52E+02" ? I have some other files that are like that, since I have to skip the first two entries, and these entries can be of any type (they are attributes of each grid line). Again same shape like above but instead of  "eta=    1" i have "4.52E+02 2.52E+02". The fortran option always works,it simply says skip that entry.Is that possible in Matlab?Could you also explain me why your code worked with x= and not with eta=?Or better I dont get why it worked with x=.

Comment: The format string `%s %s` also eats `4.52E+02 2.52E+02`. `%s` reads consecutive non-whitespace characters. This allows you to skip any entry FORTRAN style. The format string I showed you first, `x= %d` only worked with `x= ` followed by an integer number, because it explicitly specified so. For any further help, please refer to the documentation of `scanf`.

Comment: I already read the manual, my bad I missed the role of x= inside the format. Thanks again for the remark, but anyways the code you provided still does not work. If you copy and paste my gridfile on a text file gridfile.txt and you copy and paste your snippet in Matlab, it gives the error "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch" on the line before the end statement.

Comment: I just tried my code in MATLAB, and you're right, it wouldn't work that way. See my edits. The additional argument tells `fscanf` how many fields to read at most, that now prevents it from reading to far with the format specifier `%s %s`. Now the expected count is provided for each single invocation of `fscanf`. This should be safer for other cases you might run into as well.

Comment: Ok thanks this is the final answer. Please edit and replace fscanf(fin, '%s %d', 2)  with fscanf(fin, '%s %s', 2)  to allow for the same generality of the fortran code.